# I need a program to display user input digit and sum of those digits

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DigitSum
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int num, sum = 0, r;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a Number : ");
        num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        while (num != 0)
        {
            r = num % 10;
            num = num / 10;
            sum = sum + r;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("The sum of the digits in the number: " + num + " is " + sum);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

This program will take a user input number (eg. 123) and will return (The sum of the digits in the number: 0 is 6).

I need to know how I can change my code so that the program will output (The sum of the digits in the number: 123 is 6).

EDIT: Thanks for all the input everybody. I actually managed to figure it out the night I posted the problem but I'm sure someone else could use the help. I ended up keeping the while loop and saved the value of num by using a secondary variable before the loop occurs.

I realized afterwards that a while loop was probably the most convoluted way I could have solved the problem but I am glad I did because it taught me to re-evaluate the way I approach a code if I have a problem.

Comment: Use a debugger, set breakpoints, single step through your code. Compare expected values with actual values. What goes wrong? Where exactly?

Comment: Looks like first year of school exercises. Try it your self, ask exactly what you didn't understand. You are making pretty basic mistakes. Think about it, it wont get easier!

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware until I re-read my code that the while loop was changing the num value and dumping it when the loop finished. I figured it out myself but I'm glad to see all the input that was given by the community. It was a good lesson to learn that it's better to move slow and figure out the best way to solve a problem before writing any of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help.

```
static void Main()
{
     Console.WriteLine("Enter a Number : ");

     string input = Console.ReadLine();
     int num, sum = 0;

     if (int.TryParse(input, out num))
     {
         for (; num > 0; num = num / 10)
         {
             sum = sum + num % 10;
         }

         Console.WriteLine("The sum of the digits in the number: {0} is {1}", input, sum);
     }
     else { Console.WriteLine("Invalid number format."); }

     Console.ReadKey();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are changing num.

take a copy of it. 
after

```
num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

safe a copy like

```
int numOutput = num;
```

and print it like

```
Console.WriteLine("The sum of the digits in the number: " + numOutput + " is " + sum);
```

and another hint. When you use string outputs you can do this for better readability:

```
Console.WriteLine("The sum of the digits in the number: {0} is {1}", numOutput, sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of `num` so that you can still print it out at the end even if you needed to count it down during the summation:

```
num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int originalNum = num;

// …

Console.WriteLine("The sum of the digits in the number: " + originalNum + " is " + sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are modifying`num` in your `while` loop. You can store `num`'s value in another temporary variable, say `int temp = num`, just before the `while` loop. Then, when you output, replace the `num` with `temp` in

```
Console.WriteLine("The sum of the digits in the number: " + num + " is " + sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DigitSum
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a Number : ");

        var num = Console.ReadLine();

        var sum = num.Select(c => int.Parse(c.ToString())).Sum();

        Console.WriteLine("The sum of the digits in the number: " + num + " is " + sum);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```